# Entity doctrine format

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In doctrine I created entities name Products. It is showing like this.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Products
*/
class Products
{
    /**
    * @var integer
   */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
```

and so on...I don't find the above way normal as generally it is like below format.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Products
*
* @ORM\Table()
*        @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\AcmeBundle\Repository\ProductsRepository")
*/
class Products
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=100)
```

...

My question is, what I have done wrong, that the I am not able to get the Entity files in the proper format.

thanks

Comment: how did you generate entities ?

Comment: From the console, I created them.
      php app/console docrtine:generate:entity

I chosed "yml" thats why it didn't generate.
thanks for your reply.
really appreciated.
Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you didn't generate your Products entity using annotation but you used yml or xml.

Comment: Yeah I chose "yml" instead of annotation.
Problem solved.
Thanks

Comment: @Robert put the question as answered for others. Welcome :)